# jquery tab ajax loading new page

Tags: jquery

When I ajax load a new page on the tab the jquery script that is contained is within $()  doesn't get triggered .
Is there a better solution for this.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax_page.html">Ajax Tab 1</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The second tab gets it content from the server. the ajax_page has a jquery script in $(function(){
$(#id).dialog();  // This would not get loaded as this is with the document ready event..
// which i guess would not be triggered in a tab...

});
THnks
Coool

Comment: Can you show us some code samples?  It would make it easier for us to help you if you gave us something to work with.

Comment: it seems that it doesn't work in FF ...but works in IE ???

Comment: I think the questions should have been what happens when a page get loaded from server into a tab when it gets active..will the script get executed on ready event and will new scripts get downloaded....

Answer (score 1):

Can you move the script from your ajax_page into your main tabs page and then use the tabs load method which will invoke after the page has been loaded into the tab

e.g

```
$('.selector').tabs({
   load: function(event, ui) { 
     //check tab index is 1 (ajax_page)
     if ( $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected') === 1 ){
         //your script for ajax_page here
     }
   }
});
```